# Zend ServiceManager using setter injection

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

in symfony i can use the setter injection for services via `call` option (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html)

The example from the symfony documentation:

```
class MessageGenerator
{
    private $logger;

    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    // ...
}
```

service.yml

```
services:
    App\Service\MessageGenerator:
        # ...
        calls:
            - method: setLogger
              arguments:
                  - '@logger'
```

I need this behaviour for my zend project. i want to inject a `InputFilter` into my `FormFieldSet`.

I didn't find anything about this in the zend documentation. Can i use something like this or exist a better solution for my problem in zend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this question and your previous question about Forms, Fieldsets and InputFilters, I'm thinking you want to achieve something similar to the following use case.

#### Use case

You have a

- Location Entity
- Address Entity
- Location has a OneToOne to an Address (required, uni-directional)

#### Requirements

To manage the Location, you'll need:

- LocationForm (-Factory)
- LocationFormInputFilter (-Factory)
- LocationFieldset (-Factory)
- LocationFieldsetInputFilter (-Factory)
- AddressFieldset (-Factory)
- AddressFieldsetInputFilter (-Factory)

#### Configuration

To configure this in ZF3, you'll have to do add the following

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        AddressFieldset::class  => AddressFieldsetFactory::class,
        LocationForm::class     => LocationFormFactory::class,
        LocationFieldset::class => LocationFieldsetFactory::class,
    ],
],
'input_filters' => [
    'factories' => [
        AddressFieldsetInputFilter::class  => AddressFieldsetInputFilterFactory::class,
        LocationFormInputFilter::class     => LocationFormInputFilterFactory::class,
        LocationFieldsetInputFilter::class => LocationFieldsetInputFilterFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

#### Forms & Fieldsets

In the `LocationForm`, add your `LocationFieldset` and what else your Form needs, such as CSRF and submit button.

```
class LocationForm extends AbstractForm
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name'    => 'location',
            'type'    => LocationFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);

        //Call parent initializer. Adds CSRF & submit button
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

(Note: my `AbstractForm` does a bit more, I would suggest you have a look [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form/blob/master/src/Form/AbstractForm.php), such as remove empty (child fieldsets/collections) Inputs so data is not attempted to be created in the DB)

In the `LocationFieldset`, give add Inputs for the Location, such as a name, and the `AddressFieldset`:

```
class LocationFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name'     => 'name',
            'required' => true,
            'type'     => Text::class,
            'options'  => [
                'label' => _('Name'),
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type'     => AddressFieldset::class,
            'name'     => 'address',
            'required' => true,
            'options'  => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => false,
                'label'                => _('Address'),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the `AddressFieldset` just add Inputs for the Address Entity. (Same as above, without the Fieldset type Input)

#### InputFilters

To validate the Form, you can keep it very simple:

```
class LocationFormInputFilter extends AbstractFormInputFilter
{
    /** @var LocationFieldsetInputFilter  */
    protected $locationFieldsetInputFilter;

    public function __construct(LocationFieldsetInputFilter $filter) 
    {
        $this->locationFieldsetInputFilter = $filter;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add($this->locationFieldsetInputFilter, 'location');

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

(The `AbstractFormInputFilter` adds CSRF validator)

Notice that we simply `->add()` the LocationFieldsetInputFilter, but we give it a name (2nd parameter). This name is used later in the complete structure, so it's important to both keep it simple and keep it correct. Simplest is to give it a name that one on one matches the object of the Fieldset it's supposed to validate.

Next, the `LocationFieldsetInputFilter`:

```
class LocationFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    /**
     * @var AddressFieldsetInputFilter
     */
    protected $addressFieldsetInputFilter;

    public function __construct(AddressFieldsetInputFilter $addressFieldsetInputFilter) 
    {
        $this->addressFieldsetInputFilter = $addressFieldsetInputFilter;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add($this->addressFieldsetInputFilter, 'address'); // Again, name is important

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'name',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => [
                    ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                    ['name' => StripTags::class],
                    [
                        'name'    => ToNull::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'type' => ToNull::TYPE_STRING,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => StringLength::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 255,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### Factories

Now, you must bind them together, which is where your question about Setter injection comes from I think. This happens in the Factory.

A `*FormFactory` would do the following:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $inputFilterPluginManager = $container->get('InputFilterManager');
    $inputFilter = $inputFilterPluginManager->get(LocationFormInputFilter::class);

    /** @var LocationForm $form */
    $form = new LocationForm();
    $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter); // The setter injection you're after

    return $form;
}
```

A `*FieldsetFactory` would do the following (do the same for Location- and AddressFieldsets):

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    /** @var LocationFieldset $fieldset */
    // name matters! Match the object to keep it simple. Name is used from Form to match the InputFilter (with same name!)
    $fieldset = new LocationFieldset('location'); 
    // Zend Reflection Hydrator, could easily be something else, such as DoctrineObject hydrator. 
    $fieldset->setHydrator(new Reflection()); 
    $fieldset->setObject(new Location());

    return $fieldset;
}
```

A `*FormInputFilterFactory` would do the following:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $inputFilterPluginManager = $container->get('InputFilterManager');

    /** @var LocationFieldsetInputFilter $locationFieldsetInputFilter */
    $locationFieldsetInputFilter = $inputFilterPluginManager->get(LocationFieldsetInputFilter::class);

    // Create Form InputFilter
    $locationFormInputFilter = new LocationFormInputFilter(
        $locationFieldsetInputFilter
    );

    return $locationFormInputFilter;
}
```

A `*FieldsetInputFilterFactory` would do the following:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    /** @var AddressFieldsetInputFilter $addressFieldsetInputFilter */
    $addressFieldsetInputFilter = $this->getInputFilterManager()->get(AddressFieldsetInputFilter::class);
    $addressFieldsetInputFilter->setRequired(true);

    return new LocationFieldsetInputFilter(
        $addressFieldsetInputFilter
    );
}
```

**Note**:

- Setting an InputFilter as (not) required is something I've added [here](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form/blob/master/src/InputFilter/AbstractInputFilter.php)
- If your InputFilter (such as AddressFieldsetInputFilter) does not have a child InputFilter, you can can skip getting the child and straight away return the new InputFilter.

---

I think I covered it all for a complete picture. If you have any questions about this, please comment.

Comment: hm, there many unclear questions in the process to change my example. so in my case, the `FieldSetFactory` isn't called, and the `Hydrator` isn't set. i have to implement getArrayCopy(). but i want to use the `ClassMethods` Hydrator. but i like your way to solve it

Comment: The FieldsetFactory not being called is a common cause of doing `$form->setFieldset(new Fieldset())` instead of `$form->setFieldset($container->get(Fieldset::class))`. Using the appropriate ServiceManager causes the Fieldset to be supplied using the Factory registered in the config instead of a straight up "new class()". Make sure your config is present and make sure you're using the right ServiceManager. (For Form & Fieldsets it's `$container->get(Fieldset::class)`, for InputFilters it's `$container->get('InputFilterManager')->get(InputFilter::class)`.

Comment: ok, think i have to play something more with zend. its slightly different from symfony handling. but for this special case the answer from tasmaniski will be more fit to my question

Comment: While initializers (tasmaniski's answer) do what you want them, please do read the docs and note: `While convenient, initializer usage is also problematic. They are provided primarily for backwards compatibility, but we highly discourage their usage.` and `Instead, we encourage you to inject all necessary dependencies via the constructor, using factories. If some dependencies use setter or interface injection, use delegator factories`. Of course, if it's the one time, by all means. But if not, slippery slope ;) If it's a new project or one being upgraded, I would advise factories instead.

Comment: Ok, thats a reason to step over the initializer. So in Symfony there's something easier to use DI. But i want to learn to use zend too. Big thanks for your usefull help. i marked your post as answer, cause of the hint from the docs :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you need are **Initializers** from [Zend Service Manager](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/configuring-the-service-manager/#initializers).

The initializer can be a class that is called whenever a service has been created. 
In that class, you need to check the type of service that is created, and if it's appropriate type than inject whatever you want.

To register one Initializer add in config under **service_manager** key:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'initializers' => [
       MyInitializer::class
    ],
]
```

and then just create that class

```
class MyInitializer implements InitializerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $instance)
    {
        // you need to check should you inject or not
        if ($instance instanceof MessageGenerator) { 
            $instance->setLogger($container->get('logger'));
        }
    }
}
```

You need to have registred **MessageGenerator** in zend-servicemanager also. In this way, when you try to retrive **MessageGenerator** from SM, after creation MyInitializer is called.

Comment: Beware: overuse of initializers may cause unnecessary overhead since every service retrieved from service locator would pass through registered initializers. While having a few application wide initializers are fine, they should be avoided as much as possible.